# iOS UITests - How to get XCUIElement list which exist in current view

Tags: ios, xcode, testing, automated-tests, xcode-ui-testing

I am required to get a list of XCUIElement which are exist in current view.
For example,

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
let allElements = app.otherElements.allElementsBoundByIndex
```

returns the full list of xcuielements, but i want to get only the elements that are hittable and exists in current view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want the full list of elements, rather than just `otherElements`, which does not include buttons, labels and other common view types, you must filter by element type `.Any`.

Elements which do not exist will not appear in the list by default, but you can use a loop to filter by `hittable` to restrict the list to only those items which are on-screen.

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
let allElements = app.descendantsMatchingType(.Any)
var allHittableElements = [XCUIElement]()
for i in 0..<allElements.count {
    let element = allElements.elementBoundByIndex(i)
    if element.hittable {
        allHittableElements.append(element)
    }
}
```

Quite a slow but simple solution.

For a faster solution, you can make `XCUIElementQuery` conform to `Collection` and use `Collection.filter`.

Comment: Does allHittableElements hold only the elements which are on current visible screen? It would be helpful if you can guide how to use XCUIElementQuery. Thanks for help.

Comment: This video explains how to use XCTest for UI testing: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/406/

Answer (score 1):

### Functional approach for (Swift 5.0 )

```
/**
 * ## Example:
 * hittableElements(query: XCUIApplication().descendants(matching: .any)).count // n
 */
func hittableElements(query: XCUIElementQuery) -> [XCUIElement] {
    return (0..<query.count).indices.map { i in
        let element = query(matching: .any).element(boundBy: i)
        return element.isHittable ? element : nil
    }.compactMap { $0 }
}
```